# How to remove the brackets from array

Tags: vue.js

So I have color box: green, blue, orange and red, when I mousehover to different color, the "detailsItem" change regarding the color box.

It's working, but I would like just to know, in the browser, it keeps showing: [ "rare", "comfy" ] include with description, how to remove [" "]

so it's showing only the text, ex: rare, comfy.

```js
 el: "#app",
  data: {
    variants: [
        {
          variantDetails: ["soft", "cheap"]
        },
        {
          variantDetails: ["rare", "comfy"]
        },
    ],
},

 computed: {
    detailsItem: function () {
      return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantDetails
    }
  }
```

```css
.color-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Description: {{detailsItem}}</p>


<div v-for="(variant, index) in variants" class="color-box" v-on:mouseover="updateProduct(index)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the array as a string when returning in `detailsItem`.

```
detailsItem: function () {
  return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantDetails.join(', ')
}
```

You can do this in the template as well (assume `detailsItem` remains as not changed):

```
<p>Description: {{ detailsItem.join(', ') }}</p>
```

Comment: Just 1 more question, if let say I want to list the description using ul li, how I suppose to do that? in my case: <ul><li>Description: {{detailsItem}}</li></ul>, output: • Description: soft, cheap, but I want to do: • soft, • cheap

Comment: keep `detailsItem` unchanged and then use a `v-for`, `<ul><li v-for="item in detailsItem">Description: {{ item }}</li></ul> `

Comment: Thanks, but right now it separates all the alphabet, ex: • s • o • f •t • , Is there a way to make it: • soft, • cheap

Comment: Make sure `detailsItem` returns an array, i.e. no `join` in this case.

Comment: Okay, it's working now, originally I have this code: <ul>
          <li v-for="detail in details">{{detail}}</li>
        </ul> but didnt realize, I need to change details to detailsItem, thanks a lot